# How can I show numbers on an inline ordered list?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Login</li>
    <li>Address</li>
    <li>Shipping</li>
</ol>
```

It shows the decimal numbers fine, but when I set the `<li>` to inline or inline-block, the numbers vanish! I saw other places online mentioned that I have to ensure I have enough margin and padding. and I am sure that I do (10px of each!) Is there some other reason the numbers might be disappearing?  I know from firebug that as soon as I uncheck `inline` they come back.

The CSS is:

```
ol {
  padding: 20px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Try increasing the margin value and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Just to be thorough, have you tried more than 10px?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but it can be solved by floating left instead of `display: inline`

See https://jsfiddle.net/CMKzK/

```css
ol {
    padding: 20px; 
    list-style-type: decimal;

}
ol li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: That's quite unfair, only float for such a layout

Comment: centering dynamic floating content might just be impossible

Comment: This isn't a real solution: when one of the li is long enough to start wrapping, the entire thing reverts back to the traditional list. A counter is needed with inline displayed li.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```css
ol
{
  /* List will start at 25 + 1 = 26 */
  /* Remove the 25 if you want to start at 1 */
  counter-reset: LIST-ITEMS 25;
}

li
{
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

li:before
{
  content: counter( LIST-ITEMS ) ".";
  counter-increment: LIST-ITEMS;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</li>
  <li>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
  <li>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</li>
  <li>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</li>
  <li>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non</li>
  <li>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about old versions of IE, you can use [automatic counters and numbering](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters)

Otherwise you should specify the numbers manually (@Babiker's solution), or `float` your `li`'s (@Eric Fortis' solution).

Comment: This is awesome... Way better than floats! I can't believe how long I've been a front-end dev and didn't know about this... :(

Answer (score 2):

### Modern Approach - Use Flexbox

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ol li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Login</li>
  <li>Address</li>
  <li>Shipping</li>
</ol>
```

More info on Flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: Now *this* is brilliant. Thanks for adding it to this Q&A!

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around the problem of ol numbers getting pushed around by left-floating elements with the following:

```
li {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display:block;
}
.number {
    display:list-item;
    position:absolute;
}
.first-item {
    float:left; 
    /* revise margin to your needs */       
    margin-left:35px;
}
.second-item {
    float:left;
}
```

given the following DOM:

```
<ol id="playlist">

        <li>
            <div class="number"></div>
            <a class="first-item" href="#">click here</a>
            <div class="second-item">some detail</div>
        </li>
</ol>
```

seems to work with inline-block elements as well.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working with IE11. All the list-item numbers are 1.