# Children don't inherit style despite declaration on ancestor

Tags: html, css

I declared `display: inline` on `body` but the elements are still displayed in block fashion. Please help me understand the concept.

Declaring `display: inline` directly on `li` works: They will display in inline fashion. But why doesn't inline apply to them when declaring on `body`?

```css
body {display: inline}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>1234</li>
    <li>5678</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I also tried with `display: inherit` on `li`, but it still displays in block fashion, and also removes the markers which I don't want:

```css
body {display: inline}
li {display: inherit}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>1234</li>
    <li>5678</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `display` is not inherited: Setting the `<BODY>` to `display: inline` won't affect its children's `display` value.

Comment: If I wanna display inline to be inhertiable by all the children's display value ,then what would be the code?. I tried <style>
body {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inherit;
}
</style>
 but it still shows in BLOCK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Inherit `display`

Setting `display` on an element *will not* have its children inherit the value:

```css
.wrapper {display: inline}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>First text.</div>
  <div>Second text.</div>
</div>
```

While you can declare elements to inherit `display` from their ancestors, *I do not recommend* this (generally):

- Declaring elements to inherit `display` requires a declaration just as much as declaring a specific `display` value.
- If the selector is too unspecific, elements with sensible default values will lose those values.

It is important to choose good selectors for your use case. For your short example it is fine to have a generic selector, like `body *` (in words: "All descendants of `BODY`") which uses the [universal selector `*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) and a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)  .

**Note:** Using a combinator generally does *not* select "sub-selections" itself, e.g. `BODY` of selector `body *` will *not* be selected. Also note that the *descendant combinator* is less specific than the [child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Here is an analogous example:

```css
.wrapper * {display: inline}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>First text.</div>
  <div>Second text.</div>
</div>
```

If however you still want to declare the elements to *inherit* `display`, here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {display: inline} /*Set the value to inherit*/
.wrapper * {display: inherit}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>First text.</div>
  <div>Second text.</div>
</div>
```

## Lists and `display`

Lists' default `display` value is `block`, and the value of its children
(`LI`) is `list-item`. If you simply want to get rid of the markers, declare the list `list-style-type: none`:

```css
ul {list-style-type: none}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First item.
  <li>Second item.
</ul>
```

But you can also declare the list and its children (`ul, ul>*`) as `display: inline`. Note that removing padding requires another declaration.

```css
ul, ul>* {display: inline}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First item.
  <li>Second item.
</ul>
```

### Inline list with markers

If you want to inline the list-items with markers, there are several possibilities:

You can keep [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker)s of inline list-items by declaring the [list as `display: inline-flex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368934/13561410).

**Sidenote:** `::marker`s are by default [`outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) the list-item's [principal box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368934/13561410), which means they can obstruct view of other boxes. Declare the list (or its items) as [`list-style-position: inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#nowrap) to keep the markers inside the list-item's box to prevent such overflow.

**Note** that [`flex-wrap: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#nowrap) is its default, which is unlike regular text flow. Use [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#wrap) to have the list-items (and their content) flow like regular text:

```js
// Ignore; for handling radio inputs
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const list = document.querySelector("ol");
form.addEventListener("input", evt => {
  const className = evt.target.name === "position" ? "inside" : "wrap";
  // Classes for applying non-default values are named after the values
  const state = evt.target.value === className;
  
  list.classList.toggle(className, state);
});
```

```css
ol {display: inline-flex}
.inside {list-style-position: inside}
.wrap {flex-wrap: wrap}

/*Ignore; for presentational purposes*/
ol {margin: 0; padding: 0}
li {border: 1px solid darkgray}
section {margin-block: 1.2rem}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    List type:
    <label for="i-outside">
      <input id="i-outside" name="position" type="radio" value="outside" checked> Outside
    </label>
    <label for="i-inside">
      <input id="i-inside" name="position" type="radio" value="inside"> Inside
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    Wrapping:
    <label for="i-nowrap">
      <input id="i-nowrap" name="wrap" type="radio" value="nowrap" checked> No-wrap
    </label>
    <label for="i-wrap">
      <input id="i-wrap" name="wrap" type="radio" value="wrap"> Wrap
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<ol>
  <li>A very long named item that hopefully overflows its box, and
  <li>An item, and
  <li>Another short item, and
  <li>another very long named item that too should overflow its box.
</ol>
```

You can also use custom "markers" via the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

**Sidenote:** With a [custom-styled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles) [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters), you can recreate e.g. `list-style-type: georgian` counters:

```css
ol {counter-reset: li-counter}
li {counter-increment: li-counter}
li::before {content: counter(li-counter)". "}

/*Ignore; for presentational purposes*/
ol, li {padding: 0; display: inline}
```

```html
A list consisting of
<ol>
  <li>one item and
  <li>another item.
</ol>
```

### List-items don't inherit `display`?

You asked why the following didn't result in the `LI`s to inherit the `BODY`'s `display` value:

```css
body {display: inline}
li {display: inherit}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>First item.
    <li>Second item.
  </ul>
</body>
```

That is because—while `BODY` *is* declared as `display: inline`—the list in between has the default `display` value of `block`. Since inheritance happens from the element's immediate ancestor, the list-items will inherit the value `block` from the list.

### [Accessibility concern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#accessibility_concerns)

Lists are semantic elements, and by default are interpreted as such by the browser. But changing their styles may change how the browser interprets them, potentially reducing their semantic down to a generic text-containing element.

Therefore it is generally good to ensure that lists are interpreted as lists by declaring the list and its items via the [ARIA-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) [`role`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/list_role) as [`list`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/list_role) and [`listitem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listitem_role), respectively. This *overrules* the browsers decision to interpret the element as a list, even if the browser would have decided not to interpret it as a list because of some CSS.

Another point is that pseudo-elements (e.g. `::marker`, `::before`) are technically not part of the document, and can therefore not be interacted with (e.g. [selecting or copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392279/13561410)). If you need them as part of the document, then literally include them in the document.

Comment: if I wanna need markers along with an inline approach, how do I code that ?.Refer ul,ul * {display: inline;
    list-style-type: georgian;
}
<ul>
  <li>First item.
  <li>Second item.
</ul>

Comment: @JamesC Refer to my edits for more details: You can use `display: inline-flex`, or mock markers with pseudo-elements like `::before`.